# Add DLLs folder

Tags: c#, .net, dll, directory

I have a c# .net app.
I'm using a WebKitBrowser.
The problem is that the app does not work if i don't put all the webkit DLLs into the debug/release folder.
What i'm trying to do, is to put all these files into a folder like debug/WebkitFiles and all the files to be token from there.
Any help? thanks

Comment: Are these native libraries, and further statically called or are they fully fledged .NET referenced libraries?

Comment: They are DLL's WebKitBrowser libraries.
Not required at the time of design, but are necessary when running.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

[<probing> and <privatePath>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx)

Read up on the [`<assemblyBinding>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e.aspx) tag in MSDN as well:

Note the changes go into your `app.config` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can xcopy the files in your post-build event, under the project properties

Additionally, how did you first referenced the WebKitBrowser DLLs?

If you expect .NET do bind to an assembly but it is failing, do the following:
  1. Open the Visual Studio Command Prompt
  2. Type 'fuslogvw'
  -- every load of an .NET assembly will be registered in the console

Answer (score -1):

Put your DLLs where you want then add a reference to them and set "copy local" to true. If you want to keep dependencies in a sub-folder you have to modify your assembly manifest file.

Comment: The "copy local" problem is that it puts all the files in the debug/release folder, and i want it to be on a separate folder.